# how to animate all the elements in the box when I hover on it?

Tags: html, css

I want to animate(only change colors actually) all the elements that are in `.price-box` when I hover on it.

Here's the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/tyngfud6/

I want to do it only in css if it's possible.

The final result should look like sth similar to this:

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQSXm.png)

Comment: its just a jsfiddle link. There is no code

Comment: Right, sorry. This link should work :  https://jsfiddle.net/tyngfud6/

Comment: If you want hovering on one element to animate several elements, you will have to resort to javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you need to add to get `hover effect` same as sample image.

```
#price .price-box:hover {
    background-color: #27c7ab;
}
#price  > .container > .price-box:hover > .circle-price{
  background:white;
}
#price  > .container > .price-box:hover > .circle-price > p{
  color:#27c7ab;
}
#price  > .container > .price-box:hover > h1{
  color:white;
}
#price  > .container > .price-box:hover > button{
  background:white;
  color:#27c7ab;
}
```

Additional changes for remaining box needs to be done by you and will be much similar to above code.

```css
#price {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#price .label-price {
 font-size: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #26bfa1;
 margin-left: 10px;
}



#price .price-box {
 border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
 width: 330px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 margin:75px 10px;
 float: left;
 position:relative;
 text-align: center;
}

#price .price-box:hover {
 background-color: #27c7ab;
}
#price  > .container > .price-box:hover > .circle-price{
  background:white;
}
#price  > .container > .price-box:hover > .circle-price > p{
  color:#27c7ab;
}
#price  > .container > .price-box:hover > h1{
  color:white;
}
#price  > .container > .price-box:hover > button{
  background:white;
  color:#27c7ab;
}
#price .price-box .white-circle {
 height: 55px;
 width: 55px;
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 border-radius: 100%;
 border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
 position: absolute;
 top:-35px;
 left: 136px;
}

#price .price-box .grey-circle {
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 background-color: #c2c2c2;
 border-radius: 100%;
 border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
 position: absolute;
 top:-20px;
 left: 151px;
}

#price .price-box h1 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #26bfa1;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-top: 30px;

}

#price .price-box .circle-price {
 border-radius: 100%;
 border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
 width: 130px;
 height: 130px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 top:30px;
 left: 100px;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;

}

#price .price-box .circle-price p:first-of-type {
 background-color: transparent;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #c7c7c7;

}

#price .price-box .circle-price sup {
 font-size: 16px;
 vertical-align: super;
}

#price .price-box .circle-price p:nth-of-type(2) {
 background-color: transparent;
 margin-top: -15px;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #c7c7c7;
}

#price .price-box p {
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 10px 25px;
}




#price .price-box p:first-of-type {
 background-color: #e4e4e4;
 color: #909090;
 margin-top: 185px;

}

#price .price-box p:nth-of-type(2) {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 color: #8c8c8c;
}

#price .price-box p:nth-of-type(3) {
 background-color: #e4e4e4;
 color: #909090;
}

#price .price-box p:nth-of-type(4) {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 color: #8c8c8c;
}

#price .price-box button {
 font-size: 15px;
 color:white;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 border-radius:10px;
 background-color:#26bfa1;
 border: none;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px;
 left:100px;

}
```

```html
<section id="price">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <p class="label-price">Cennik</p>
            <div class="price-box">
                <div class="white-circle"></div>
                <div class="grey-circle"></div>
                <h1>Basic plan</h1>
                <div class="circle-price">
                    <p>85<sup>99</sup></p>
                    <p>PLN/MSC</p>
                </div>
                <p class="option1">Zakup towaru + serwis</p>
                <p class="option2">Dowoz</p>
                <button>DOŁĄCZ</button>
            </div>
            <div class="price-box" "price-box2">
                <div class="white-circle"></div>
                <div class="grey-circle"></div>
                <h1>Basic plan</h1>
                <div class="circle-price">
                    <p>95<sup>99</sup></p>
                    <p>PLN/MSC</p>
                </div>
                <p class="option1">Zakup towaru + serwis</p>
                <p class="option2">Dowoz</p>
                <p class="option3">Gwarancja 5 lat</p>
                <button>DOŁĄCZ</button>
            </div>
            <div class="price-box" "price-box3">
                <div class="white-circle"></div>
                <div class="grey-circle"></div>
                <h1>Basic plan</h1>
                <div class="circle-price">
                    <p style="margin-left:0">211<sup>00</sup></p>
                    <p>PLN/MSC</p>
                </div>
                <p class="option1">Zakup towaru + serwis</p>
                <p class="option2">Dowoz</p>
                <p class="option3">Gwarancja 6 lat</p>
                <p class="option4">Porady projektanta</p>

                <button>DOŁĄCZ</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thank you. You helped me very much. Now I understand it much more better :)

Comment: Welcome @adrian_25, it's good that you understood how it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adrian_25

If you want to change color when you hover on it :

```
.price-box .child-element {
    default styles;
}

.price-box:hover .child-element {
    hover styles;
}
```

Based on your jsfiddle :

```
#price .price-box:hover button {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color:#27c7ab;
}
```

Watchout here, what did you try to do ?

```
<div class="price-box" "price-box2">
    <!-- Stuff -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css3 transition` i.e: `transition: background-color 0.5s linear;`

And make your hover styles like

```
#price .price-box .white-circle {
    background-color: green;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

#price .price-box:hover .white-circle {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tyngfud6/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you want one-element hovering to manipulate multiple elements, you will have to resort to javascript. Using jQuery, you can do this by using `toggleClass` as such:

```
$(function() {
    $(".price-box").hover(function() {
        $(".price-box").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Then giving a class of `active` to the elements with the properties you want. Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tyngfud6/3/

Answer (score 0):

Adding `transition: background 3s` to `#price .price-box` will animate background on hover over 3secs.

```
#price .price-box {
    border: 2px solid #dbdbdb;
    width: 330px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    margin:75px 10px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
  transition: background 3s;  /*secs value can change*/
  -webkit-transition: background 3s; /*secs value can change*/
}
```